# Sending an unsent EML with a specified 'From'-address

Tags: email, outlook, eml

For an application we want to offer our users generated EMLs which they can open in Outlook 2010 and send after doing minimal changes to the contents of the mail or adding attachments or recipients. One of the things we set when generating the EML is the 'From'-address, which we set to a Mailbox. All users have access to this mailbox but when they open the EML and try to send it, an error is always returned:

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

recipient1@foo.com
You can't send a message on behalf of this user unless you have permission to do so. Please make sure you're sending on behalf of the correct sender, or request the necessary permission. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.
```

However if the user opens the mail, sets the mailbox manually by selecting the mailbox in the 'From'-combobox (note that nothing visually changes in the email) and then sends the mail, the mail is successfully delivered. It seems to me that I'm missing something in the EML in order to successfully specify the 'From'-address. I'd like to believe that the mail should be able to be sent successfully as long as the user, opening the mail, has access to the mailbox.

An example of an EML is the following:

```
From: Test-Mailbox@foo.com
To: recipient1@foo.com, recipient2@foo.com
Cc: ccRecipient@foo.com
Bcc: bccRecipient@foo.com
Message-ID: <29094346.1.1409121155408.JavaMail.tester@wd34376>
Subject: subject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
boundary="----=_Part_0_30562042.1409121155299"
X-Unsent: 1

------=_Part_0_30562042.1409121155299
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

body goes here
------=_Part_0_30562042.1409121155299--
```

Comment: Note that it does work, when you DON'T set the From header. Outlook falls back to the default sender address in this case. Obviously you explicitely want to set the sender in your case, but this information could still be useful for people who can live with the default sender address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a way how to correctly set the mailbox as the sender but it involved specifying a macro in VB in Outlook by setting the SentOnBehalfOfName in the Open-event of the MailItem. Not exactly my preferred solution...